# Filter JSON data against JSON schema in Python

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I am looking for Python module to filter JSON data against schema.

For example,
there is JSON data:

```
{
    "system" : {
        "state" : "enabled",
        "id" : 5,
        "keys" : [
            { "key_id": 12, "key": "filename.key" }
        ]
    }
}
```

And there is JSON schema:

```
{
    "system": {
        "id": "system",
        "required": true,
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "state": {
                "id": "state",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "id": "id",
                "required": true,
                "type": "number"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the schema does not contain "keys" property.

I need some tool, which could filter the JSON data using the schema and provide following JSON as an output:

```
{
    "system" : {
        "state" : "enabled",
        "id" : 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Filtering is not a function of JSON Schema.

Comment: I would assume that you need a json schema validator in order to identify what needs to be filtered. So I think you could ask in https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema to see if there is any way to use that package to easily implement the filtering.

Comment: I have just added a github issue to ask this, https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/707 . If someone responds with easy way to do this I would post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no tool, for filtering JSON data against schema, I have resolved my task as follows.

Created template of expected JSON file. Actually it is already filtered JSON file, but without data.

```
{
    "system" : {
        "state" : "",
        "id" : 0
    }
}
```

Then go through the data file and the template file and just copy values from one to another for properties that exist in both files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonschema` to validate your json against the schema, check this example

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {"type" : "object","properties" : { "price" : {"type" : "number"},"name" : {"type" : "string"},},}
validate(instance={"name" : "Eggs", "price" : 34}, schema=schema)
```

If no exception is raised by validate(), the instance is valid

Comment: Thank you, but I am asking about filtering JSON data. I expect to provide extended JSON file, and get a smaller one as an output. Something like pass the data through a colander.

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of JSON schema is to validate given JSON input against a defined schema. As @Relequestual says in a comment you cannot use JSON schema to filter out fields directly.

If you need to remove only `keys` field then you do not need to use JSON schema at all. You could simply remove the field from JSON input.

In case you need to filter out a bunch of unexpected fields from the input you could use JSON schema to `identify` those fields. But you need to do filtering part manually or using another library since JSON schema cannot do that for you.

You could use `additionalProperties` field to restrict unexpected keys.

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "required":false,
  "properties":{
    "system": {
        "id": "system",
        "required": true,
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "state": {
                "id": "state",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "id": "id",
                "required": true,
                "type": "number"
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

This will give a validation error like following

> Message:
>   Property 'keys' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.
>   Schema path:
>    #/properties/system/additionalProperties

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for. But hope it helps.